# PHP-FPM FilesMatch and ProxyPassMatch Interchangeability?

Tags: php, apache, reverse-proxy

Are FilesMatch and ProxyPassMatch interchangeable when proxying php-fpm, and if so are there any circumstances where one would be used over the other?

Currently I am using ProxyPassMatch via a vhost block as per the many online tutorials.

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/"
</FilesMatch>
<Proxy "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/" enablereuse=on max=10>
```

**vs**

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/
```

Answer (score 4):

One important difference is **ProxyPassMatch** ignores deny access of .php files in .htaccess.

**FilesMatch** is better.

See https://ma.ttias.be/apache-2-4-proxypass-for-php-taking-precedence-over-filesfilesmatch-in-htaccess/